# Using prolog to solve finding all employees who work under a person, including indirectly.

Tags: prolog

If i have employee entries that show an employee's name and all of the people who work directly under that person, such as:

```
employee(joe, []).  
employee(billy, []).  
employee(mike, [joe, billy]).  
employee(megan, [mike]).  
employee(tom, [joe, megan]).  
employee(bob, [billy]).  
employee(kate, [tom, bob, joe]).
```

How do I get a list with all people working under, directly and indirectly, a given employee?

Like if I enter:

```
bossof(megan, Output).
```

to get all people working under megan, it gives me an output of:

```
Output = [mike, joe, billy].
```

So far I have been trying to do it recursively this way:

```
bossof(X, A) :- getloweremployees(employee(X,Y), A).

getloweremployees([],_).
getloweremployees([H|T], A) :- A = append([H], getloweremployees(employee(H,Z),B), getloweremployees(T, C)).
```

But it is just giving me an output of false. The main part that is confusing me is figuring out how to break down the lists to try each piece of data.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Prolog predicates are not like functions, so `getloweremployees(employee(X,Y), A).` doesn't do at all what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are requiring that your facts be as stated in your original post, then you can define the following rules which will determine the employees of a given "boss":

```
% Boss is the boss of Employee if Employee' is a member of Boss' employees
%
boss_of(Boss, Employee) :-
    employee(Boss, Employees),
    member(Employee, Employees).

% Boss is the boss of Employee if E is one of Boss' employees, and E is a boss of Employee
%
boss_of(Boss, Employee) :-
    employee(Boss, Employees),
    member(E, Employees),
    boss_of(E, Employee).
```

Which will succeed if `Boss` is a boss of `Employee`:

```
| ?- boss_of(megan, Output).

Output = mike ? ;

Output = joe ? ;

Output = billy

yes
| ?-
```

Then collect all of the responses using `findall/3`:

```
boss_of_all(Boss, Employees) :-
    findall(E, boss_of(Boss, E), Employees).
```

And as a test query:

```
| ?-  boss_of_all(megan, Employees).

Employees = [mike,joe,billy]

yes
| ?-
```

Personally, I would name your facts `employees/2` instead of `employee/2` since the facts yield all of the employees of a given boss, not just one. Establishing a logical and consistent naming convention in Prolog (as in any language) will help make the program easier to understand and to design.

---

As an alternative approach, however, I think it would be simpler, more flexible, and more canonical to represent your employee facts as individual boss/employee relationships.

```
employee(mike, billy). 
employee(mike, joe). 
employee(megan, mike).  
employee(tom, joe).
employee(tom, megan).
employee(bob, billy).  
employee(kate, tom).  
employee(kate, bob).  
employee(kate, joe).
```

With these facts, you would have a query such as:

```
| ?- employee(mike, X).

X = billy ? ;

X = joe

yes
```

So Prolog will backtrack to get each solution (employee for `mike`). Your facts, with list arguments, can be derived from these with a simple predicate:

```
employees(X, Employees) :- findall(E, employee(X, E), Employees).
```

Such that the following query would then act in the way your current fact database does:

```
| ?- employees(tom, Employees).

Employees = [joe,megan]

yes
| ?-
```

Given all that, you can then say that *`B` is a boss of `E`* if either of the following is true:

> `B` is an *employee* of `E`
>
> `X` is an *employee* of `B` and `X` is a *boss_of* `E`

These can be expressed as:

```
boss_of(B, E) :- employee(B, E).
boss_of(B, E) :- employee(B, X), boss_of(X, E).
```

The behavior of `boss_of/2` is as demonstrated in the first solution above. You have a predicate `boss_of(X, Y)` that is true if `X` is the boss of `Y`. If you really need to collect these results in a list, you would define `boss_of_all/2` exactly as shown above in the first solution.

Comment: I love the alternate encoding!

Comment: What if I want only the indirect subordinates? The cases in which the Boss is direct in the facts should not be displayed.

Comment: @JoséAlgarra you would change `boss_of(B, E) :- employee(B, E).` to `boss_of(B, E) :- employee(B, X), employee(X, E).`

Answer (score 1):

a recursive approach could be:

```
boss_employees(Boss, Employees) :-
    employee(Boss, Direct),
    findall(L, ( member(D, Direct), boss_employees(D, L) ), Lt),
    flatten([Direct, Lt], Sub),
    sort(Sub, Employees).
```

instead of flatten/2, we can use append/2, since the nesting is always 1 level

```
    ...
    append([Direct|Lt], Sub),
    ...
```

Comment: `append/2` is indeed *much* preferable here, and also in very many other cases!